# Trying to use atomic_write on pickle object

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle, atomic, dump

I want to store a pickle object (not only dict that can get string representation) to disk in a "safe" way so it will do fsync, os.replace and so.. as in atomic_write do for strings.

this is my code:

```
from atomicwrites import atomic_write
from dataIO import pk
import pickle

dict1 = {'goo':1,'mos':2}
with atomic_write('foo.txt', overwrite=True) as f:
    f.write(pickle.dumps(dict1, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL))
```

What am I am doing wrong? I am getting:

```
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

**Solution:**

```
from atomicwrites import atomic_write
from dataIO import pk
import pickle, json

dict1 = {'goo':1,'mos':2}
with atomic_write('foo.pkl', mode='wb', overwrite=True) as f:
    #f.write(json.dumps(dict1))
    f.write(pickle.dumps(dict1, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL))

dictname = pickle.load(open("foo.pkl", "rb"))
print(dictname)
```

But I don't understand why load is working and loads is not.
Can someone verify my code is correct ?

Comment: try `atomic_write('foo.txt', 'wb')` to write bytes to file

Comment: atomic_write('foo', 'wb', overwrite=True) - > TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: mode='wb' seems to work

Comment: oh, sry, got confused between `write` and `atomic_write` api